# Javascript and image_tag return

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I work with emoticons and i try to replays this:

```
for (smile in emt) {
    patterns.push([
        new RegExp(smile.replace(/([\(\)\[\]\{\}\.\?\^\$\|\-])/g, "\\$1"), "gi"),
        '<img src="'+url+emt[smile]+ '" />'
    ]); 
}
```

to this:

```
for (smile in emt) {
    patterns.push([
        new RegExp(smile.replace(/([\(\)\[\]\{\}\.\?\^\$\|\-])/g, "\\$1"), "gi"),
        '<%= image_tag("'+url+emt[smile]+ '") %>'  ///here is change
    ]); 
}
```

but it only display image_tag as a text - why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot interlace your JavaScript and Ruby this way. JavaScript runs client-side, long after the ERB has been evaluated server-side.